# How can I add and track files in git without tracking the directories they are in?

Tags: git, github, version-control, directory, wildcard

### [image: untracked files]

As you can see from the picture, I have some files nested in some directories. For example in the '../../roadTrip/' directory I have a file called 'main.cpp'. I want to track ONLY this file and not the directories it is in, because that is the only file I want to push to my remote repo. I tried ignoring the directories the file was in, in the .gitignore file by using wildcards, but it ignores the file also. Is there any way I can achieve this effect without having to literally take out the file from the nested directories and then push it?

---

--UPDATE!
Below is a screenshot of my github remote repo. It shows the whole directory, and when I open it, the file is inside. This means the file was successfully pushed, but I don't want that. I want the file to be pushed alone without the directories it is in.
[image: file uploaded]

Something along the lines of this:

---

[image: source file]

Comment: Please be consistent: is the file called `Source.cpp` or `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

> I want the file to be pushed alone without the directories it is in.

That is *not* possible with Git. Your remote repository will have the same structure the your working tree of your local repository. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I tried that, and I was able to successfully track the file, but when I pushed it to my remote repo, the whole directory in which the file was located was pushed instead of just the file

Comment: @BigD *[...] the whole directory in which the file was located was pushed instead of just the file*.This indicates that the contents of your `roadTrip` folder are already being tracked by Git. Run `git rm -r --cached <path-to-roadTrip-dir>/`, then `git add <path-to-roadTrip-dir>/main.cpp`, then make a commit.

Comment: I tried that and now then it said 'Use -f if you really want to add them. fatal: no files added'

Comment: Right...that's what I believed, but I had hope something will work out. I will have to manually move it out of the directory then.